# Xamarin.iOS AddObserver not firing for change event for udpate to UIView.Window

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement a lifecycle effect in Xamarin.Forms, but am having trouble for the iOS version. For some reason, I can't seem to observe the window changing notification event. Below is my code:

```cs
public class CustomLifeCycleEffectRouter : PlatformEffect
{
    private const NSKeyValueObservingOptions ObservingOptions = NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New;

    UIView? _nativeView;
    CustomLifeCycleEffect? _lifeCycleEffect;
    IDisposable _isLoadedObserverDisposable;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        _lifeCycleEffect = Element.Effects.OfType<CustomLifeCycleEffect>().FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"The effect {nameof(CustomLifeCycleEffect)} can't be null.");

        _nativeView = Control ?? Container;

        _isLoadedObserverDisposable = _nativeView?.AddObserver("window", ObservingOptions, isWindowAttachedObserver);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        _lifeCycleEffect?.RaiseUnloadedEvent(Element);
        _isLoadedObserverDisposable.Dispose();
    }
    
    private void isWindowAttachedObserver(NSObservedChange nsObservedChange)
    {
        if (_nativeView.Window != null)
            _lifeCycleEffect?.RaiseLoadedEvent(Element);
        else
            _lifeCycleEffect?.RaiseUnloadedEvent(Element);
    }
}
```

I am well aware that the Xamarin.Community Toolkit has a similar effect, but it fires the event to early; I need it to fire when I can navigate up the hiearchy to the root parent. Can anybody see a problem?

## Edit

I've created a small sample to replicate my behaviours and issues. It can be viewed here:

https://github.com/sonic1015/LifeCycleEffectTesting

The goal is to only have the following messages in the debug output:

> $"{elementName} is already a page."

> $"{elementName} is a child of {pageName}."

and NOT these ones:

> $"{elementName} does not have a parent ???."

> $"How can {elementName} be loaded and not have a parent in hierarchy ???."

> $"WTF??? we never loaded {elementName}."

These messages can be found in the "ViewExtensions" class, and I've the goal is to have every user-created view fire off good messages.

#### One thing I've noticed:

I also included a variant of the Xamarin Community Toolkit version of the router effect in the platform project, and it actually works, with the exception that it seems if any views are templated, it will fire "loaded" when it does not yet have a parent. I think this is why it originally didn't work for me, so if I could figure out a way to work that little edge case out, I could use that version of the routing effect.

Comment: Have you set the breakpoints and see if  the debug goes to breakpoints when observing the window changing notification event?

Comment: I have, and only the NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial is observed (window is still null).

Comment: BTW, what do you mean you need fire when you can navigate up the hiearchy to the root parent? I made a small sample and create a button on load and unload effect for you, you can refer to it. If there's any question, don't hesitate to reach out to me. Thanks!

Comment: With the original XC Toolkit, on load only the first parent was not null (it was very weird to be honest). I need to keep navigating up the hierarchy until I hit a Page, but none such element existed.

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Create a `ViewLifecycleEffect` class that implements RoutingEffect in the shared project like below:

```
public class ViewLifecycleEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public const string EffectGroupName = "XFLifecycle";
    public const string EffectName = "LifecycleEffect";
 
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Loaded;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Unloaded;
 
    public ViewLifecycleEffect() : base($"{EffectGroupName}.{EffectName}") { }
 
    public void RaiseLoaded(Element element) => Loaded?.Invoke(element, EventArgs.Empty);
    public void RaiseUnloaded(Element element) => Unloaded?.Invoke(element, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**2**.In Mainpage.xmal:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MainContainer" Margin="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Button Text="CLICK TO REMOVE" Clicked="Button_OnClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button.Effects>
            <effects:ViewLifecycleEffect Loaded="ViewLifecycleEffect_OnLoaded" Unloaded="ViewLifecycleEffect_OnUnloaded"/>
        </Button.Effects>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainContainer.Children.Clear();
    }
 
    private void ViewLifecycleEffect_OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("LOADED", "Button was added", "OK");
    }
 
    private void ViewLifecycleEffect_OnUnloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("UNLOADED", "Button was removed", "OK");
    }
}
```

**3**.Create a `IosLifecycleEffect` in the iOS project.

```
[assembly:ResolutionGroupName(ViewLifecycleEffect.EffectGroupName)]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(IosLifecycleEffect), ViewLifecycleEffect.EffectName)]
namespace XFLifecycle.iOS.Effects
{
    public class IosLifecycleEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private const NSKeyValueObservingOptions ObservingOptions = NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Prior;
 
        private ViewLifecycleEffect _viewLifecycleEffect;
        private IDisposable _isLoadedObserverDisposable;
 
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            _viewLifecycleEffect = Element.Effects.OfType<ViewLifecycleEffect>().FirstOrDefault();
             
            UIView nativeView = Control ?? Container;
            _isLoadedObserverDisposable = nativeView?.AddObserver("superview", ObservingOptions, IsViewLoadedObserver);
        }
 
        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            _viewLifecycleEffect.RaiseUnloaded(Element);
            _isLoadedObserverDisposable.Dispose();
        }
 
        private void IsViewLoadedObserver(NSObservedChange nsObservedChange)
        {
            if (!nsObservedChange.NewValue.Equals(NSNull.Null))
                _viewLifecycleEffect?.RaiseLoaded(Element);
            else if (!nsObservedChange.OldValue.Equals(NSNull.Null))
                _viewLifecycleEffect?.RaiseUnloaded(Element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So listening to the superview is something I did try. I get a lot of Null exceptions with this code, but even checking for null values, All but one view does not fire (a carouselView). I'll try moving your code to a small sample and see if I have the same or different behaviour.

Comment: Excellent, I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I've added a sample to the original post. I also included the Community Toolkit variant which actually seems to work better, except it fires loaded when we have no parents for templated views. If I could work around that, I could use it.